# My car is impounded, where can I find it?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

After a mission I left my car alone. It was then impounded. I didn't pay the impound fee or steal it. Then did another mission. Where would it be now? It's not in the impound lot.

Answer (score 2):

If your car is definitly not in the impounded lot then the police might already have destroyed it.
If you have an insurance for your car, just call your insurance to get it back.